# Win Socket UDP connection-less recvfrom() Error

Tags: c++, udp, communication, visual-c++-6, winsock2

I'm working on a legacy VC6 application, that uses winsocket to listen to a UDP port for incoming packets. However I am getting the following errors. If I use **`WSAGetLastError()`** I get **`WSAECONNRESET`**, which if I read the description, doesn't seem to make sense, because its saying that remote host forcibly closed the socket, But I want use UDP connection-less manor, so it shouldn't matter what the other machine is doing... we should just listen. If I check the **`errno`** and use **`sterror()`** I get the following message. **`"No such file or directory"`**. (I think this it's enum is EIO, according to http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/recvfrom.html)

I've had some success in narrowing down the issue, it appears if I take out a **`sendto()`** call, that calls back on the same port as the **`recvfrom()`**, the code seems to work ok. So something with that **`sendto()`** is putting in a bad state.

I'm looking for suggestions on why this socket is going bad, and either how to prevent or recover.

**Edit**

Here is the other weird part, if do the setup again for that socket (after a recvfrom() fails)... it all seems to work, even additional calls to **`sendto()`** don't seem trigger a recvfrom() fail, which in turn would call the setup again..

**CODE**

```
 static VOID SetupSocketAddress( SOCKADDR_U &saRx, int nRTDPort )
    {
        memset(&saRx.saIPX, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IPX));
        saRx.saIPX.sa_family = AF_IPX;                          // IPX type address
        memset(saRx.saIPX.sa_netnum,0x00,4);                    // we may have to get this number
        memset(saRx.saIPX.sa_nodenum,0xff,6);                   // broadcast address
        saRx.saIPX.sa_socket=(unsigned short)nRTDPort;      // socket number
    }

void CRealTimeData::SetupSocket( CRealTimeData * lpRTD, BOOL &bDone, SOCKADDR_U &saRx, int nRTDPort, SOCKADDR_U &saFrom, int &cbAddr, 
    DWORD &dwLocalAddress, int &nMaxIpIpxBuf, char * &pbyIpIpxRxBuf, int nFlags, BOOL bDo)
{
    char    szErrorCode[32];
    int     nReturn = 0;

    if (lpRTD->m_eSourceType == V7_RTD_IPX)
    {
        // open IPX socket
        // packet type = 4
        lpRTD->m_Socket=socket(AF_IPX, SOCK_DGRAM, NSPROTO_IPX+4);
        if (lpRTD->m_Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            nReturn = AddSocketErrorToEventViewer( lpRTD);
            bDone = TRUE;
        }

        // Socket must be bound prior to calling recvfrom()
        // setup address
        SetupSocketAddress(saRx, nRTDPort);


#ifdef  _DEBUG_IPX
        // test changing host number to network number
        // we can't actually change though, because other programs use it this way
        u_short nNetPort=0;
        int nRet=WSAHtons(lpRTD->m_Socket, (unsigned short)nRTDPort, &nNetPort);
        TRACE(_T("RTDIpxThread: Host Port=%04x  Net Port=%04x RTD Input=%d \n"),nRTDPort, nNetPort, lpRTD->GetInputNumber());
#endif
        // setup address for Sending Data on RTD
        SetupSocketAddress( lpRTD->m_saRTD, nRTDPort );

        // copy address - Why are we copying the address just over right later (in recvfrom() )? -NG
        memcpy(&saFrom.saIPX, &lpRTD->m_saRTD.saIPX, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IPX));

        cbAddr = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IPX);
    }
    else
    {
        // open IP socket
        lpRTD->m_Socket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_IP);        // ??? should this use IPPROTO_UDP???
        if (lpRTD->m_Socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            nReturn = AddSocketErrorToEventViewer( lpRTD);
            bDone = TRUE;
        }

        // Socket must be bound prior to calling recvfrom()
        // setup address
        memset(&saRx.saIP, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
        saRx.saIP.sin_family = AF_INET;                                         // IP type address
        saRx.saIP.sin_port=htons((u_short)nRTDPort);                            // PORT number
        saRx.saIP.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);                            // ADDRESS number

        // setup for Sending Data on RTD port
        memset(&lpRTD->m_saRTD.saIP, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));
        lpRTD->m_saRTD.saIP.sin_family = AF_INET;                       // IP type address
        lpRTD->m_saRTD.saIP.sin_port=htons((u_short)nRTDPort);          // PORT number
        lpRTD->m_saRTD.saIP.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);    // ADDRESS number

        // copy address - Why are we copying the address just over right later (in recvfrom() )? -NG
        memcpy(&saFrom.saIP, &lpRTD->m_saRTD.saIP, sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

        cbAddr = sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN);

        char    szHostName[MAX_PATH+1];
        if (gethostname(szHostName, MAX_PATH)==0)
        {
            hostent *phe=gethostbyname(szHostName);

            dwLocalAddress = *(DWORD*)&phe->h_addr_list[0];
        }
    }   // end IP socket

    if (!bDone)
    {
        // enable broadcasting
        BOOL bOptVal=TRUE;
        nReturn=setsockopt(lpRTD->m_Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BROADCAST, (char *)&bOptVal, sizeof(BOOL));
        if (nReturn == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            nReturn=WSAGetLastError();
        }

        // enable reuse of address
        bOptVal=TRUE;
        nReturn=setsockopt(lpRTD->m_Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&bOptVal, sizeof(BOOL));
        if (nReturn == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            nReturn=WSAGetLastError();
        }

        // get the socket's max message size
        int nOptSize=sizeof(UINT);
        UINT nMaxMsgSize=600;
        nReturn=getsockopt(lpRTD->m_Socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_MAX_MSG_SIZE, (char *)&nMaxMsgSize, &nOptSize);
        if (nReturn == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            nReturn=WSAGetLastError();
            nMaxMsgSize=600;                // default max size
        }

        nMaxIpIpxBuf=nMaxMsgSize;                           // always create buffer that is as big as the sockets max message size
        pbyIpIpxRxBuf = new char[nMaxIpIpxBuf];     // allocate buffer for receiving data from socket

        if (!pbyIpIpxRxBuf)
            bDone = TRUE;
        else
            memset(pbyIpIpxRxBuf,0,nMaxIpIpxBuf*sizeof(char));

        // bind to address
        nReturn=bind(lpRTD->m_Socket, &saRx.sa, cbAddr);
        if (nReturn == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            nReturn = AddSocketErrorToEventViewer(lpRTD);
            bDone = TRUE;
        }

        // send data to indicate startup
        if (lpRTD->m_eProtocol == V7_RTD_ENHANCED)
        {
            int nLen=lpRTD->BuildErrorMsg(V7_ERTD_SERVICE_STARTUP, szErrorCode, sizeof(szErrorCode));
            nReturn=sendto(lpRTD->m_Socket,szErrorCode,nLen, nFlags, &lpRTD->m_saRTD.sa, cbAddr);
            if (nReturn == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                nReturn=WSAGetLastError();
            }
        }

    }   // end if not done
}
```

**Main()**

```
    nFromLen = cbAddr;
    nReturn=recvfrom(lpRTD->m_Socket, pbyIpIpxRxBuf, nMaxIpIpxBuf, nFlags, &saFrom.sa, &nFromLen);
    if(nReturn == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        SetupSocket(lpRTD, bDone, saRx, nRTDPort, saFrom, cbAddr, dwLocalAddress, nMaxIpIpxBuf, pbyIpIpxRxBuf,nFlags, FALSE);
        nReturn=recvfrom(lpRTD->m_Socket, pbyIpIpxRxBuf, nMaxIpIpxBuf, nFlags, &saFrom.sa, &nFromLen);
    }

// if i take this out no error....
    nReturn=sendto(lpRTD->m_Socket, szErrorCode, nLen, nFlags, &saFrom.sa, cbAddr);
```

Comment: please show the actual socket code

Comment: sorry this is a bit messy, but does it help?

Comment: I can't comment on your IPX code, as I have never worked with IPX sockets before. But your call to `socket()` for UDP should be using `IPPROTO_UDP`, your use of `gethostbyname()` to get the local IP is wrong and error prone, and you are enabling `SO_BROADCAST` even though you are not sending broadcasts.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think the SO_BROADCAST is because we don't know who is listening to response, we want to get all machines on the next work. Ah, but I think I know what your saying, because I use the from parameter from recvfrom() to send the response back on. Is setting this really going to have ill effects?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm not even sure why we do this if (gethostname(szHostName, MAX_PATH)==0)
{
 hostent *phe=gethostbyname(szHostName);

   dwLocalAddress = *(DWORD*)&phe->h_addr_list[0];
  } Dosen't even look like we use the localaddress for anything... but surely this can't be screwing the whole thing up?

Comment: you don't need to enable `SO_BROADCAST` on a UDP socket unless you are sending packets to an actual broadcast IP. As for `dwLocalAddress`, you would have to look at how the caller of `SetupSocket()` actually uses it, but since you are binding to `INADDR_ANY` then `dwLocalAddress` might end up being the wrong value for the caller to use if the machine has multiple IPs installed. It really depends on how it gets used.